# Does eating pork increase promiscuity?

Tags: nutrition, psychology, sexuality

According to the book [Pork](https://books.google.com/books?id=W5urAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=pork%20swap%20wives&source=bl&ots=zfm0wHEtVY&sig=P4RT2_HxQSNZfb7sRhBOu4lXCFo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyqIb6lJzRAhVD4yYKHdUIDNI4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=pork%20swap%20wives&f=false) (alternative [pdf version](http://www.shia-maktab.info/index.php/en/library/books/english?format=raw&task=download&fid=33)):

> People who use pork are gradually influenced by its inherent sensuality; and when this trend influences the minds, shamelessness becomes the norm of the day; modesty and probity become old fashioned ideas which are discarded on the altar of sensuality and perversion.
>
> QUESTION: This assertion is very very strange. How can you prove that pork creates shamelessness?

Author goes on to discuss swinging/wife swapping, insisting that eating pork causes this.

> Let us divide the regions of the world in two groups: Pork-eating and non-pork-eating; and then see in which regions such shameful behaviour is ... In pork-eating areas you find Europe and Americas. And it is in Europe and Americas that you will find such **promiscuity**; and not in the non-pork-eating regions.

...

> pork-eating sociologists, doctors and psychologists lend a professional aura of respectability to adultery, **promiscuity** and sexual perversions ... It was this “Shamelessness” to which I had referred; and it is found in pig-eating societies only. What more proof do you need? These societies pull the humanity down to the level of wild beasts. Pig turns the man into pig.

...

> pork is extremely harmful not to the body only but to the mind also, no matter how hygienic the conditions in which pigs are kept now-a-days.

Comment: I've wiped the discussion to allow folks to focus on the *current* revision of this question... Reminder: please keep a civil tone and focus on comments that can bring clarity; [be nice](/help/be-nice).

Comment: OK -- this is clearly not working. The previous versions were closed because of good reasons, going back in that direction is not making the question better. Also, back-by-back argument won't make this question better. If the community feels this is not notable then they can vote to close (or reopen) accordingly. Also this can be discussed on [meta]. There are 13 flags, 80 deleted comments and 9 deleted answers. This community deserves everybody's respect and civility.

Comment: Has someone told the Pork Producers Council about this?  I sense a marketing opportunity here!  Joking aside, how do you respect a question which, apart from being impossible to test, seems aimed at expressing attitudes which a lot of us consider to be sheer insanity?  And FWIW, they were just as insane when expressed by the pork-eating Victorians &c.

Comment: @jamesqf I think it is falsifiable to a degree by finding societies that don't eat pork, yet are still promiscuous.

Comment: @DavePhD: Sure, you can do correlational studies - the Inuit, modern Israel, the pork-eating Victorians, a number of fundamentalist Christian groups who like their ham & bacon yet have similar attitudes to sex.  But the real problem, I think, is that by doing so we'd be justifying the author's mental illness.

Comment: There is virtually nothing that _someone_ hasn't claimed to be an aphrodisiac...

Comment: @keshlam This claim isn't about pork being an aphrodisiac.  Instead, it is about pork causing people to have sex with people other than their spouses.  Adultery, swinging, wife swapping.

Comment: The author doesn't seems to use very scientific based arguments, his position as a Islamic Scholar doesn't help either.
I hate to use wikipedia to fact check things but here is the only place where I found info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%27id_Akhtar_Rizvi

Comment: @LéonDonnet-Monay I didn't realize the author was so famous